# Firefox about:cache-entry parameters: setting limits for a memory entry hexdump?

Tags: firefox, memory, video, cache

So, I was viewing an IP camera video stream from a smartphone in Firefox 118.0.1; tried to set its properties, and the IP camera app on the smartphone, which is in an inaccessible location, crashed.

I would like to save at least one frame from the video stream, if possible.

So, I thought I'd look into `about:cache?storage=memory` in Firefox - and it turns out, *something* is there:

[image: cache_memory_video]

Now the thing is, it says here 4193198 bytes for /video, and 484 bytes for /recordbtn.png, and "Expired immediately" for both.

So, if I click on the /recordbtn.png, I get "Cache entry information" page, with a hexdump below (at the end of the page), at a link: `about:cache-entry?storage=memory&context=O^privateBrowsingId=1&partitionKey=%28http%2C10.0.XXXXXXXX%2C8080%29,p,&eid=&uri=http://10.0.XXXXXXXX:8080/recordbtn.png`

[image: cache_entry_recordbtn_png]

So, apparently, even if it says "Expired immediately", the data for the cached entry is still there.

Apparently, it is impossible to save these memory cache entries as binary files directly from Firefox, since in all questions I've found like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210558/download-firefox-browser-cache-file the answers are like "Convert those hex encoded bytes into a binary file".

Anyways, I click on the cache entry /video - and, again I get "Cache entry information" page - but there is no hexdump at the end of the page! It kinda makes sense, because it will take quite a lot of memory to hexdump 4193198 bytes in HTML.

But then, even if the cached data is there:

- I cannot save it as binary file directly from Firefox
- I cannot even hexdump it in its entirety from `about:cache-entry` page

So, I thought, maybe it is possible to set arguments/parameters/options to the `about:cache-entry` URL, akin to original `hexdump`'s `-s, --skip offset` and `-n, --length` - so I can at least get a hexdump of a snippet of the cached entry? Then maybe I could retrieve enough data, to reconstruct a single frame from the cached stream ....

Unfortunately, it is nearly impossible to find which parameters might `about:cache-entry` URL support: some copypasta has spread on the Internet, so all I get is:

[image: cache_entry_requires_pamaters_search]

... "Requires parameters". Great - *which* parameters does it require?

So, my question is: are there any `about:cache-entry` URL parameters, so that I can limit the hexdumped data to a snippet of the entire cached entry (and in that way, obtain enough data to at least decode one frame from the cached stream)? If not, is there any other way to save/export this /video in-memory cached entry as a binary file?

Comment: If you're lucky, you will have something in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\2lrpqlkx.default-1624267825608\cache2\entries`. The parent folder of `cache2` will be different for you.